# If $x < 90^\circ$, such that $\sin x = \frac {2}{\sqrt{5}}$, find $\cos (x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $x < 90^\circ$, such that $\sin x = \dfrac {2}{\sqrt{5}}$ find $\cos (x)$ without using a calculator and hence evaluate $ \dfrac {1+\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)}$ in the form $m+n\sqrt{5}$, where $m+n\in\Bbb Z^+$

and

> If $y < 90^\circ$, such that $\sin y = \dfrac {1}{\sqrt{5}}$ find $\cos (y)$ and $\tan (y)$ without using a calculator and hence evaluate $8 \sin y + \cos y+6\tan y$ in the form $m+n\sqrt{5}$, where m and n are positive integers.

I'm a little lost on how to approach this, I'm so used to these type of questions but at a more difficult level that these two questions confuse me, and I'm 100% that they are not difficult.

So far I've done this but I don't think it's correct:

$$\frac {2}{\sqrt{5}} \frac {\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}} = \frac {2\sqrt{5}}{5}$$

Therefore,

$$x=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac {2\sqrt{5}}{5}\right)+2\pi n$$

$$x=\pi-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac {2\sqrt{5}}{5}\right)+2\pi n$$

Which I don't think they have anything to do with the above...

Comment: Do you know that $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =1$ ?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but I only have $\sin^{1}$

Comment: @scoff, if you have $\sin^1$, how could you find $\sin^2$?

Comment: But $\sin^2{x}=(\sin{x})^2$....

Comment: You could also use that $\sin{x}=\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}$ and use the difference formula for $\cos{(x-y)}$

Comment: Um.... If you have $\sin^1$ then $\sin^2 = \sin^1 \cdot \sin^1$, yes?

Comment: You do realize the $\sin^2$ is "sine squared"  i.e. "sine multiplied by itself"?  So if $\sin x= K$ then $\sin^2 x = K^2$.... And so if $\sin x = \frac 2{\sqrt 5}$ then $\sin^2 x = \frac 2{\sqrt 5}\frac 2{\sqrt 5} = \frac 45$.

Comment: There's not enough information to determine the sign of $\cos x$. Is it understood that $x>0$ too?

Comment: @HansLundmark  For $\cos x < 0$ and $\sin x > 0$ we'd have to have $x$ in the second quadrant and $90 < x < 180$ if we assume $0\le x < 360$ or $-180 \le x \le 180$.  To find a value so that $x < 0$ we'd have to have $-270 \le x \le -180$ and although that is technicall possible, I *really* think we can presume for this course and this level, that yes either $x$ is defined to be between $-180$ and $180$ or between $0$ and $360$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ so

$(\frac 2{\sqrt 5})^2 + \cos^2 x=1$ so .....

> $\frac 45 + \cos^2 x=1$

.

> $\cos^2 x = 1-\frac 45 =\frac 15$

.

> $\cos x = \pm \sqrt {\frac 15} = \pm \frac 1{\sqrt 5}$.

.

> But $x< 90^\circ$ so $\cos x > 0$.

.

> So $\cos x = \frac 1{\sqrt 5}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

We have
$$
\cos^2(x) = 1- \sin^2(x)
$$
Thus
$$
\cos^2(x) = 1 - \frac{4}{5} = \frac{1}{5}
$$
Then ($x < 90°$)
$$
\cos(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: What's left to finish?

Comment: @fleablood "and hence evaluate $\dfrac {1+\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)}$".

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^2{x} + \cos^2{x} = 1$

$\cos^2{x} = 1 - \sin^2{x}$

$\cos{x} = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2{x}} \quad \land \quad \sin{x} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \quad \land \quad x < 90^{\circ}$

$\Longrightarrow \cos x = \sqrt{1 - \Big(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \Big)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$

Can you continue?

Comment: "Can you continue?"?  To where?

Comment: To do the other question he means - thank you the three of you